# My heroku app keeps crashing even though the IP is properly set

Tags: node.js, api, heroku, mongodb-atlas

I was doing a online course. I have come to a part where I set up this api: https://github.com/devslopes-learn/mac-chat-api for the chatapp. Now, I am trying to set this up in heroku with `mongoDB Atlas`. I have made sure my current IP was set in the whitelist of mongoDB Atlas and even then it was not working. So, I set the IP Address to `access from anywhere` but still it keeps showing up the same error everytime I look into the `heroku logs --tail`. This is the error:

```
2020-07-16T07:03:40.854889+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-07-16T07:03:40.877353+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-1073-aws
2020-07-16T07:03:40.877809+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" 
"/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2020-07-16T07:03:40.878166+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v6.10.2
2020-07-16T07:03:40.878504+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
2020-07-16T07:03:40.878844+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-07-16T07:03:40.879115+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! slacky-slack@1.0.0 start: `node 
./dist/index.js`
2020-07-16T07:03:40.879591+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-07-16T07:03:40.879839+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-07-16T07:03:40.880060+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the slacky-slack@1.0.0 start script 
'node ./dist/index.js'.
2020-07-16T07:03:40.880353+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of 
node.js and npm installed.
2020-07-16T07:03:40.880572+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with 
the slacky-slack package,
2020-07-16T07:03:40.880804+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2020-07-16T07:03:40.881050+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2020-07-16T07:03:40.881262+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node ./dist/index.js
2020-07-16T07:03:40.881549+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue 
for this project with:
2020-07-16T07:03:40.881787+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs slacky-slack
2020-07-16T07:03:40.882033+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their 
info via:
2020-07-16T07:03:40.882254+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls slacky-slack
2020-07-16T07:03:40.882475+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output 
above.
2020-07-16T07:03:40.894068+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-07-16T07:03:40.894456+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any 
support request:
2020-07-16T07:03:40.894699+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2020-07-16T07:03:40.960885+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-07-16T07:03:41.006599+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2020-07-16T07:03:43.283042+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET 
path="/" host=chattychatchatsmackapp.herokuapp.com request_id=cd345b5f-ef1f-4eed-abbc-a25a2a2c086f 
fwd="180.190.35.125" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-07-16T07:03:45.742164+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET 
path="/" host=chattychatchatsmackapp.herokuapp.com request_id=191ac0fa-3a56-4658-9e7f-c87f9aa0d080 
fwd="180.190.35.125" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I have been looking for a solution for nearly 4 hours now and I haven't found any that works for me. Sometimes it works when I restart but then when I click `Open app` again it simply crashes. I don't know what I did wrong. I have tried everything I could find.

Any help is really appreciated.

**EDIT**

I managed to find a more-or-less kind of solution. It's up now but in random times it crashes then starts back up. I wanted to ask if this is normal? I don't really know much about this and couldn't find much with my searches on google.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error and ended up just needing to delete my MongoDB Atlas cluster and start anew. Whatever was going wrong with the connection between Atlas and Heroku was fixed with a new cluster and the requisite new connection string over on Heroku's config variables for the project.